# Trouble debugging Blender python using Visual Studio 2019

Tags: python, debugging, blender, visual-studio-debugging

I'm trying to investigate some of the operations that Blender does.  The particular operation I want to investigate is implemented in Python inside Blender.

I downloaded the code, and followed https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Windows and https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Tools/Debugging/Python_Visual_Studio without, I thought, any trouble.  I used VS 2019 instead of 2017, however I had no trouble getting Blender to start up inside the debugger.

The problem is that, when I set a breakpoint inside the Python module in which I'm interested, at runtime the breakpoint ends up disabled, and hovering over it I get "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document."

I've tried both the Debug and Release solution configuration.  VS 2019 is set to "Python/Native Debugging."  I've tried setting the breakpoint inside the copy of the Python file that's inside the VS project, and also opening the second copy it makes inside "build_windows_Full_x64_vc16_Release\bin\Debug\3.1\scripts" or "build_windows_Full_x64_vc16_Release\bin\Release\3.1\scripts".

So, clearly I've missed a step or done something wrong.

Suggestions?

Comment: Many conditions will cause this issue. You need to first confirm that the symbols have been loaded. When debugging stops(hit one breakpoint or choose Debug > Break All), Debug > Windows > Modules > check if the related module is loaded > right-click > select Symbol Load Information… and match the real path to confirm the symbols file(.pdb) is there. Besides, you set the breakpoints for `.py` file not for other files right?

Comment: I'm aware of the issue of a DLL or something like that not getting its symbols loaded.  But the Python files don't have corresponding .pdb files to load.  Seems like VS is treating them as if they were C or C++ files and expecting them to be bundled into one of the binary modules.

And, yes, I put the breakpoint on a line in the .py file.

Comment: Maybe the symbols are related to Blender instead of Python file?

Comment: It is the Python file in which I'm trying to set the breakpoint, and in which the complaint is given.

The instructions in the links I gave above say this should work.  I've followed the steps, but it doesn't work.  So, I'm trying to figure out what's changed since they wrote those instructions.